# Filter Function in Python - Difference between solutions

Tags: python, filter

The goal is to identify the mutual elements between both lists below:

```
a = [1,2,3,5,7,9]
b = [2,3,5,6,7,8]
```

I tried the below:

```
a = [1,2,3,5,7,9]
b = [2,3,5,6,7,8]

for i in a:
    filt1=list(filter(lambda x:x==i,b))

print(filt1)
```

The expected result is:

```
[2, 3, 5, 7]
```

The following code works:

```
a = [1,2,3,5,7,9]
b = [2,3,5,6,7,8]

filt2=(list(filter(lambda x: x in a,b)))

print(filt2)
```

Doesn't it perform like the one I've been trying? What's the difference between them?

Comment: Add a `print(filt1)` to your `for` loop and you will see your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`filt1` is being overridden on every iteration of your for loop.

you end up with `[]` because the last number (9) is not in `b`.

define it beforehand, and add the filter lists to it.

try this:

```py
a = [1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 9]
b = [2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8]

filt1 = []
for i in a:
    filt1 += list(filter(lambda x: x == i, b))

print(filt1)
```

Output:

```
[2, 3, 5, 7]
```

Comment: NOTE: this answer is just about what is the difference, this is not the best solution for finding the list you need, see @Roman's answer for a much faster (and shorter) one.

Answer (score 2):

Using `filter` won't be an efficient solution in such case, `set`s intersection is a reasonable way:

```
a = [1,2,3,5,7,9]
b = [2,3,5,6,7,8]
common_nums = list(set(a) & set(b))
print(common_nums)   # [2, 3, 5, 7]
```

---

As for issues:
in your 1st approach you are reassigning `filt1` on each iteration so you won't get an expected result (a common items won't be accumulated).

```
for i in a:
    filt1=list(filter(lambda x:x==i,b))  # <---
```

But I wouldn't advice to fix it but eliminate it in favour of `set` approach.

Comment: So, what's the difference between the two pieces of code in question?

Answer (score 0):

No, your first solution is not the same as the second one.

You are iterating through a list, and for each elemnt, you are creating a new list.
And the result is just list for the last element.
You can fix it by creating additional list:

```
temp = []
for i in a:
    filt1=list(filter(lambda x:x==i,b))
    temp.extend(filt1)

print(temp)
```